# d3js: make cloud from pre-existing word weights

Tags: d3.js

In the demos I have found, d3js wordcloud itself is *counting* words and *eliminating stop* words.

I want to supply my own word count (weighting) and eliminate stopwords myself, because:

- I have a very long list of stopwords
- The analyzed text is scattered about in many directories

I've already worked up a routine to recurse the directories and make json data of word counts.

Can the d3js generate the wordcloud from supplied data? I guess to phrase it another way, is the code modular enough to just have d3js do the cloud render only?

Any examples in the wild?

Here is pseudo code for a static html page I would create, that I would want d3js to finish into a word cloud:

```
  <body>
        <script type="application/json" id="wordcloud-data">
          {
            "words": {
                "word": [
                {
                "-count": "20",
                "-text": "red"
                },
                {
                "-count": "10",
                "-text": "blue"
                },
                {
                "-count": "25",
                "-text": "orange"
                },
                {
                "-count": "5",
                "-text": "dog"
                }
                ]
            }
          }
        </script>
        <div>word cloud here</div>
  </body>
```

I tried to find an example, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I searched more and eventually found a d3.js [simple demo](http://bl.ocks.org/ericcoopey/6382449#d3.layout.cloud.js) that helped me.

The [standard d3.js word cloud demo](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud) was bit complex for my needs as a starting point. Though I will definitely refer back to it as I progress, it is an excellent demo of advanced features.

Of note, my JSON format was almost there. This is what I need to change it to:

```
var words = [
{"text":"red","size":20},
{"text":"blue","size":10},
{"text":"orange","size":25},
{"text":"dog","size":5}];
```